# Check the selected value of dynamically created dropdown boxes

Tags: html-select

I am dynamically adding rows to a table.  Each row has input fields, as well as, drop down fields.  When I select 'Other' in the drop down I want to disable the Comments field.  How do I check the dropdown box of a dynamically added row?

The following is my code.  The row inserts work fine but, I don't know how to check the selected value of the drop down box.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function addRow() {
   var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
   var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;   
   var iteration = lastRow;
   var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

   var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
   var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration-3);
   cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);

   var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(1);
   var sel = document.createElement('select');
   sel.name = 'LOCsel' + iteration;
   sel.options[0] = new Option('---Any---', '0');
   sel.options[1] = new Option('Level 0.5: Early Intervention', '1');
   sel.options[2] = new Option('Level I: Outpatient', '2');
   sel.options[3] = new Option('Level I.D: Outpatient-Detox', '3');
   sel.options[4] = new Option('Level II.1: Intensive Outpatient', '4');
   sel.options[5] = new Option('Level II.5: Partial Hospitalization', '5');
   sel.options[6] = new Option('Level II.D: IOP-Detox', '6');
   sel.options[7] = new Option('Level III.1: Halfway House', '7');
   sel.options[8] = new Option('Level III.3: Long-Term Residential Care', '8');
   sel.options[9] = new Option('Level III.5: Therapeutic Community', '9');
   sel.options[10] = new Option('Level III.7: Medically Monitoried Inpatient(ICF)', '10');
   sel.options[11] = new Option('Level III.7.D: Med.Mon.Inpatient(ICF)-Detox', '11');
   sel.options[12] = new Option('Other', '12');
   cellRightSel.appendChild(sel);

   var cellRights = row.insertCell(2);
   var els = document.createElement('input');
   els.type = 'text';
   els.name = 'Comments' + iteration;
   els.id = 'Comments' + iteration;
   els.size = 30;
   cellRights.appendChild(els);

   var cell8 = row.insertCell(9);            
   var element8 = document.createElement('input');            
   element8.type = 'text';            
   element8.name = 'txtRow'+ iteration;
   element8.id = 'txtRow'+ iteration;
   cell8.appendChild(element8);
   element8.size = 20;
   }

function validateLOC(){
   var table = document.getElementById('tblSample');
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;

   for (var i=0; i < rowCount; i++) {
var loc = table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementById('LOCsel')[i];
var strUser = loc.options[loc.selectedIndex].text;      
if (strUser = 'Other'){
   document.getElementById('Comments').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('Comments').style.backgroundColor = '#cccccc';
   rowCount--;
    i;
}
else {
   document.getElementById('Comments').disabled = false;
   rowCount--;
   i;
}
    return true;
}
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give the select box and id by adding:
sel.id = 'LOCsel' + iteration;

Then add an onclick event handler to each select box:
sel.onclick = function () {
    onLOCSelected(iteration);
};

Then add this function:
function onLOCSelected(uniqueID)
{
    //Using the uniqueID (iteration as you called it)
    //Evaluate the value of selected item & toggle the comments input accordingly
}

Hope that helps!

Comment: Here is the function I created but it still isn't working.                                                                                                                                function onLOCSelected(iteration)
{
  var loc = document.getElementById('LOCsel')[iteration];
  var strUser = loc.options[loc.selectedIndex].text;
  if (strUser = 'Other'){
    document.getElementById('Comments')[iteration].disabled = true;
   }
  else {
    document.getElementById('Comments').disabled = false;          }                                               return true;
}

Comment: Elements in the DOM have a unique id and should be looked up by that id.  You are not looking up the elements properly you should be looking them up like so:
document.getElementById('LOCsel' + iteration)
document.getElementById('Comments' + iteration)
I'm guessing you are fairly new to this, my best advice is to run your site in Chrome, open up the developer tools and use the scripts tab and console to debug your JS.  This should help you learn...

Comment: Good to hear! If you could you please mark the answer as the selected one.